# Unity findgameobjectswithtag still finds destroyed items

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, find, gameobject

In my unity program i have two function who runs in an Update() function. In one of the functions, if a conditition is met an object will be destroyed. The problem occurs when because the other function is still finding the destroyed object which gives me the error: MissingReferenceException: The object of type “GameObject” has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Why is the findgameobjectawithtag still finding a destroyed object and what can i do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Better use abstraciton over tags, they aren't much usefull.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html):

> The object obj is destroyed immediately after the current Update loop

This means that if you destroy the object and look for it in the same Update() loop, you find it because it still exists.

There are two ways to fix it:

First: when destroying an item, wait for the Update() to finish before searching for it. You can do this with a bool, or by putting the search before the Destroy, or something similar.

Second (not recommended): use DestroyImmediate (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html)